# Robocopy appears to do nothing when /MT flag is used

Tags: robocopy

This command works:

```
robocopy \\build7\d$ d: *.*  /mir  /XD "System Volume Information"  /XD "$Recycle.Bin"
```

But when I try adding the /MT flag:

```
robocopy \\build7\d$ d: *.*  /mir  /XD "System Volume Information"  /XD "$Recycle.Bin"  /MT
```

The only output I get is

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Thu Apr 09 09:11:27 2015

   Source : \\build7\d$\
     Dest : D:\

    Files : *.*

 Exc Dirs : System Volume Information
            $Recycle.Bin

  Options : *.* /S /E /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /MT:8 /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It gives me that output, and then just sits there.

I tried using the /LOG flag to redirect the output to a file, but it still just sat there with the same output, only in a file.

Is it doing something in the background that I can't see, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that your version of robocopy supports mulitthreading?

Comment: Never read that any robocopy Version does not support `mt`.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but the command does show output and finish (rather fast) with the /mt option. It is just that it does not copy any files. Seems to happen especially when combined with /xf and /xd. It is also worth noting that I copy files from a virtual share created by Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac. Without /mt, files are copied as expected, but the command is slow even when there are no changes to copy.

Answer (score 12):

In my experience, what you are seeing is normal.  When Robocopy runs using multiple threads (/MT), the output is limited to exceptions (new file, extra dir, error, etc...).  It will not show you the directory names with the file count that you are probably used to seeing.  That means that if the target is largely in-sync with the source, you will not see much output.

I don't know exactly why this is the case.  I assume that Robocopy handles the directory walking differently when there are multiple threads involved.  This difference probably makes the normal output impossible (or meaningless) to produce.

When I am running Robocopy with multiple threads, I often use the Disk tab in the Windows Resource Monitor to see what Robocopy is doing.  [How to Use Resource Monitor](http://www.pcworld.com/article/241677/how_to_use_resource_monitor.html)

Comment: When on the Disk tab, you can check "Robocopy.exe" in the "Processes with Disk Activity" section to ensure you're only seeing transfers from Robocopy. Even though I used `/MT:4`, the number of touched files started being larger than 4 over time. It appears to be starting new transfers as other files near completion.

Comment: Best answer IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  I found that this must be a super old version executing.  Cleaning up my path and being sure windows\system32 was first in the chain brought things back to normal.  Version XP0100 was from a resource kit.  Your output is like this probably because those directories are already mirrored.  It will only show files that are added/deleted.

Robocopy in general has become different.  Just doing robocopy   /e results in it doing a MIR type command where it lists all the files in  that are not in  (at least it doesnt delete them).  But /MT is not even an option any longer.  And adding it to your command string gives a note about reading "True Replication" prior to using /MIR (which i didnt even call for).  This stopped working recently as this was an program that was called for in an application i wrote, breaking the thing.  If you call "robocopy /?" /MT is no longer a listed option.  I would check which version you are using, mine is shown as
Version XP010.  This is shown on the first line when running the program.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>  robocopy C:\Intel\Config.Msi\ C:\nr /mt:5

---

### ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows     ::     Version XP010

Started : Tue Sep 19 16:17:53 2023

Source - C:\Intel\Config.Msi
Dest - C:\nr\

```
Files :
```

Options : /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

---

ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "/mt:5"

```
   Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR

         source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
    destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
           /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.

For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /? or read Robocopy.Doc.
```

NOTE: Read "True Replication" in Robocopy.Doc prior to first use of /MIR !
****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>  robocopy C:\Intel\Config.Msi\ C:\nr /mt:5 /e